# My custom edit item button takes you to the edit form...but there is no values in the fields

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-form

I am created custom forms using sharepoint designer on sharepoint server 2010.  One of the requirements is to minimize the use of the ribbon so I have it hidden via javascript and I have created a button on my new displayform.aspx .  When I click the button in the custom display form it takes me to the custom edit form but none of the values from the item are being passed into the form.

Here is the custom display form
[image: screengrab of CXDispForm.aspx]

Here is the Custom edit form (without the data from the list item being passed into it - just a description of the field itself)
[image]

To get this far I have

1. Added a button to a row at the bottom of the table using the
   SharePoint designer Insert ASP.NET control.
2. After that I changed the text that would be displayed on the button
   to something specific to my uses then right-clicked on the button
   and selected "Form actions".
3. From there I set the button to "Navigate to Page" with settings
   referenced to the custom EditItem forms url.

I think there is something I need to do at this stage to get the custom display form to show the information from the list item but I am not sure what.

My code for this area looks like this:

```
<td colspan="99" class="ms-vb" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__redirect={CxEditForm.aspx}')}">
                                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="ID" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID))" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
                            </td>
```

As many of you Code wizards might be able to tell, I am new at this... so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's a problem:

```
'__redirect={CxEditForm.aspx}'
```

You aren't passing any List Item ID to the form, so it doesn't know what item to retrieve. A typical editform will have a URL like:`/EditForm.aspx?ID=8`.

The wiring of the ListItemID should be automatically created in your custom editform, but you still need to pass the parameter.
I forget the syntax, but something like this: `'__redirect={CxEditForm.aspx?ID={@ID}}'`

Comment: I assumed it had something to do with a missing  value related to the ID but I don't know how to reference the ID of the item being viewed at the time.  I don't want every single redirect point to the item with the ID of 8 (or whatever I plug in there) I want it to reference the ID of the current Item.  I tried manually appending the '__redirect={CxEditForm.aspx}' with a "?ID=[%CurrentItem:ID%] at the end of CxEditForm.aspx like I would for a lookup value in a workflow...but it doesn't appear to be that easy.

Comment: I have tried every variation of the syntax you provided I can think of...It's not working for me.  Any other ideas?